# Why are they faking the moon landing in Diamonds Are Forever?

Tags: james-bond

There are quite a number of James Bond films that involve satellites and space travel in key ways—*You Only Live Twice*, *Moonraker*, and *Goldeneye*, for example (all showing space technology far in advance of what actually existed at the times they were released).  However, the one Bond film that always confuses me in this regard is *Diamonds Are Forever*, which seems to present two different views of outer space technology that are totally at odds.  On one hand, Blofeld has taken over Jimmy Dean's aerospace company and uses it to place a powerful laser satellite in orbit, which he is then able to use to attack sites on Earth.  On the other hand, as Bond is escaping from the laboratory where the satellite is being built, he passes through a sound stage where they are actually faking a moon landing.

The film was released in 1971, at the acme of the Apollo program—a time when there was a lot of optimism about the future of space travel.  It seems totally inconsistent to have the incredibly advanced satellite technology that drives the plot, while at the same time needing to stage fake visits to the moon.  (The moon landings were, unlike Blofeld's space laser, something that really could be accomplished with 1960s–1970s tech, after all.)  So I feel like I am missing some plot-related reason why they are faking the moon landing—something that should be eminently achievable with the technology shown in the film.  Is there such a reason?  Or did Saltzman, Broccoli, Hamilton, *et al.* just throw in the fake Apollo landing as a joke, without thinking whether it made sense in light of the rest of the plot?

Comment: I don't think James Bond is science fiction.

Comment: @user931 Not in general, but this is clearly a science fiction aspect of the story, which is on topic, as has been discussed ad nauseum

Comment: @user931 voting to leave open per [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic? (e.g. spy movies)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/337/98028)

Comment: I thought it was a test facility - "*Finding himself in an artificial moonscape complete with trainee astronauts, Bond dashes for a nearby Moon Buggy vehicle and crashes out of the centre and into one of the 007 films' most famous chase scenes.*" ; http://www.007magazine.co.uk/moonbuggy/moon_buggy.htm

Comment: I always found the futuristic looking gadgets from James Bond to be on the frontier of Science Fiction, at least in my opinion.

Comment: "Get out of that Moon Buggy"...  Goto love JB.

Comment: Can't tell me a wristwatch laser with enough power/energy to cut through steel isn't SF.  Never mind (picking a much older film) a SCUBA apparatus the size of two 7 gram CO2 cartridges plus a mouthpiece.  And the real-world goodies were sometimes on the edge -- rocket belt and JIM suit, anyone?

Comment: <s>"at the _acme_ of the Apollo program"? _I don't think that word means what you think it means._ "at the _height_ of the Apollo program"? "at the _apogee_ of the Apollo program"? Something else, perhaps, but not [acme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation).</s> Well, color me embarrassed, now that I've read that link, #TIL...

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just because you've got the technological capability to shoot a film "on location", doesn't mean that's the most economical way to do it. Whether the location is South Dakota or the Moon. That reminds me of a sci-fi story where the first rocket to the moon was built by a movie company in order to film a sci-fi movie on location.

Comment: @FreeMan - yeah, I'd argue July 20th, 1969 was peak Apollo. Sadly, by '71, it was over and they were just running out the clock. Apollo 18 was canceled and the last lunar flight was just a few months away. Might be better to say it was the nadir of the Apollo program. The public (and Congress) had pretty much forgotten NASA by that point :(

Comment: Like Valorum, I always interpreted it to be something like a training facility, not a soundstage, so in-universe, the Moon buggy was a functional prototype designed to be operated on the Moon. Of course it looks like a joke now, and I'm pretty sure it always was. I first saw it on TV in the mid 70s, and don't ever remember being able to take it seriously.

Comment: There's nothing in the screenplay to help us; https://i.stack.imgur.com/541iT.png

Comment: There's nothing of any use in the Director's Audio Commentary from the Bluray Special Edition. They talk about problems with the buggy, but nothing about the moon set

Comment: The comic adaptation says that the moon buggy was bought as surplus from NASA; https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5aedd3c72971149a59a49bfb/1530022232077-6WGP79NB7NQO563ED0FC/Diamonds+Translated_Page_11.jpg?format=500w

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because it was knee-slappingly funny at the time. In 1971, there was already quite a lot of doubt being aired about the Moon landings, and it was included here as a [throwaway gag](https://www.filmcompanion.in/features/hollywood-features/50-years-of-the-apollo-11-moon-landing-in-these-movies-it-never-happened/). The fact that the supervillains were faking the Moon landing had little connection with the rest of the movie, but it kept the audience at the edge of their seats.

Stylistically, it was like the moment in *Monty Python's Life of Brian* (1979) where Brian [falls from a height toward certain death](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il26svFhWM8), only to be picked up in mid-air by aliens who resemble Kurt Vonnegut's Tralfamadorians, then is dropped on the land again after a brief space battle. All this action is gratuitous and disconnected from the plot, but it's knuckle-bitingly funny because of the cultural references to things that aren't even supposed to exist.

Comment: I enjoyed that answer, now we wait for someone to pop on here and ask: “Are Space Aliens canon in the Holy Grail universe?”, because, stackexchange..

Comment: _"there was already quite a lot of doubt being aired about the Moon landings"_. Certainly not "quite a lot". The first book was thrown out by a disgruntled technician, one Mr Bill Kaysing, [in 1976](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing_conspiracy_theories).

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Well... I lived through this time and would have sworn that there were skeptics from the start. Supporting your statement, a search for "faked the moon landing" on Newspapers.com yielded 198 items from the 2000s and 138 from the 2010s, but only 24 from the 1990s, none from the 1980s, and a mere 4 from the 1970s, none earlier than 1977. However, the 15 June 1970 issue of the Rochester _Democrat and Chronicle_ carried a UPI article (p. 8A) saying that a "Survey shows there is wide support for theory that government and news media helped stage fake Moon landing."

Comment: From the article: "Many skeptics feel Moon explorer Neil Armstrong took his 'giant step for mankind' somewhere in Arizona. There is wide support for a theory that the government and the news media conspired to hoodwink the public with a fake telecast of a Moon landing. Others feel that man in space is infringing on God's territory." -- based on a survey of 1721 persons. Much of the article consists of colorful quotations, e.g., "I'll never believe they walked on the Moon. ... Not the Moon I see shining in the sky at night." Anyway, we didn't have to wait to 1976 for skepticism to arrive.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron I guess not. And this in spite of the fact that all the ramp-up from Mercury to Gemini to Apollo Test runs (including the accident with Apollo 1) must have been fresh in the minds *and* people were not used to getting CGI movies dropped on them every weekend.

Answer (score 16):

### They aren’t faking a moon landing

Real Apollo astronauts trained on “[mock-up](https://www.history.com/news/moon-landing-apollo-11-training-photos)” lunar surfaces that looked for all the world like film sets. Scroll down to:

> **April 22, 1969:** Astronauts Buzz Aldrin (left) and Neil Armstrong participate in a simulation of deploying and using lunar tools, on the surface of the moon, while wearing their Extravehicular Mobility Units during a training exercise. In the background is a Lunar Module mock-up.

It’s perfectly sensible for an aerospace company to be training astronauts for moon walking.

Comment: Is there any indication (**in the film**) that this is what's going on?

Comment: @Valorum Contextually, there was a lot of coverage at the time of astronauts doing training. On Skeptics we've pointed people to quite a lot of historical training and equipment imagery.

Comment: Sure, but can you offer any y'know, evidence to back up the very bold assertion in your header?

Comment: No more than there is that the scene is a “fake”

Comment: OK, but this isn't Skeptics and @Valorum's point is that we're talking about a fictional work. So the best you can say is "there's no evidence a fake Moon landing is being perpetrated in this scene". But even then, your frame challenge is still valid.

Comment: @Spencer That might be a valid point.  But the accepted answer would need to be changed too, it treats the idea that it was a fake as it was an obvious fact.

Answer (score -1):

Inexplicably, James Bond accidentally stumbles onto a movie set that consists of rocks, a lunar backdrop, and a vehicle that looks like NASA's Eagle.

> Men in spacesuits move about slowly and clumsily, as if simulating low gravity. Bond's pursuers give chase, but 007 -
> stirred, but not shaken - climbs into the lunar lander and makes his escape.

The scene is never explained.

In non-fiction context, the scene has both been described as being satirical commentary on moon landing hoax conspiracy that James Bond inadvertently stumbled on NASA faking the moon landing, an in-universe event that could happen despite the general world of James Bond already having real space stations existing around the same time. The scene has also been described as being a training facility.

Ultimately, each viewer must decide the context of the unexplained scene for themselves.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. Unless there's a writer or director saying *"the viewer needs to decide for themselves"*, there's **zero** evidence this is intended to be ambiguous.